# How to write Order by expression in JPQL

Tags: sql-order-by, jpql

PostgreSQL and MySQL offers to write expression into `ORDER BY` clause in SQL query. It allows to sort items by some column but the special values are on the top. The SQL looks like this one. ( works in Postgres )

```
select * from article order by id = 4, id desc;
```

Now I want to write it in the JPQL but it doesn't work. My attempt is:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Article.special", query = "SELECT a FROM Article a ORDER BY ( a.id = :id ) DESC, a.id DESC")
```

This is JPA 1.0 with Hibernate driver. Application server throws this exception on deploy.

```
ERROR [SessionFactoryImpl] Error in named query: Article.special
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected AST node: = near line 1, column 73 [SELECT a FROM cz.cvut.fel.sk.model.department.Article a ORDER BY ( a.id = :id ) DESC, a.id DESC]
 at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:54)
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For a named query, (ORDER BY ( a.id = :id ) or ORDER BY (:id )) won't work as DSC/ASC can't be parametrized at run-time.

1) Dynamic way if ordering element varies at runtime.

```
String query = "SELECT a FROM Article a ORDER BY "+orderElement+" DESC, a.id DESC";
entityManager.createQuery(query).getResultList();
```

2) Static way in entity bean if ordering element is fixed.

Field level:

```
@OrderBy("id ASC")
List<Article> articles;
```

Method level:

```
@OrderBy("id DESC")
public List<Article> getArticles() {...};
```

Comment: What does the `orderElement` mean? Is it only the name of column or it can be the expression? So the first option is using native query? I don't want it. And the second option is good, I know it but is doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: 'orderElement' is just a parameter to be passed for which you want to order the result like (:id) in your provided query. And the query I have provided isn't native query, just creating it dynamically.

Comment: I know this is old already but what does `orderElement` really is? Can you give more example? is it `id=4`, `4`, `a.id` ? im using postgres. and tried all 3 but doesn't work in JPQL @NayanWadekar

Comment: @bumblebeen It's string variable holding a column name. You can remove it altogether & write like any plain query, if you know on what column you have to sort records.